# Alert on edit after a downvote

Tags: feature-request, alerts

I wonder if it would be possible to extend the current notification system.

Namely, if I downvote a question and that thing had an edit, I'd be happy to see that in my inbox. As possibly the cause for downvote was cleaned up and it should be undone.